# Why this first comma in this printf array?

Tags: bash, printf

I want to put a header to file but I get the first comma in the output. 
Code

```
#!/bash/bin
ids=(1 10)
filenameTarget=/tmp/result.csv
:> "${filenameTarget}"
echo "masi" > "${filenameTarget}"
header=$(printf ",%s" ${ids[@]}) # http://stackoverflow.com/a/2317171/54964
sed -i "1s/^/${header}\n/" "${filenameTarget}"
```

Output

```
,1,10
masi
```

Expected output

```
1,10
masi
```

Debian: 8.5
Bash: 4.30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You left out the

```
bar=${bar:1}
```

line from [the answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317171/4500798); you need

```
header=${header:1}
```

before your `sed` line to remove the leading comma.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `printf`, why not use bash's built-in substitutions? From the section on [Arrays](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

```
   subscripts  differ only when the word appears within double quotes.  If
   the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the
   value  of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS
   special variable, and ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a sep‐
   arate  word.   When  there  are no array members, ${name[@]} expands to
```

So you can:

```
$ IFS=,; echo "${ids[*]}"
1,10
$
```

Also you can use `sed` to insert a whole line, like:

```
$ echo masi > foo
$ IFS=, sed -i "1i${ids[*]}" foo
$ cat foo
1,10
masi
$
```

Comment: `IFS=, echo "${ids[*]}"` would pass `IFS=,` to the environment of `echo` (which wouldn't do anything with it) and would not affect the expansion of `"${ids[*]}"`. You'd need `IFS=,; echo "${ids[*]}"` or even better use `zsh` and do `echo ${(j:,:)ids}` that is use an explicit operator and avoid clobbering a default setting like `$IFS`.